# Log messages not printed by Flask in my custom Flask extension

Tags: python, flask

I wrote a little Flask extension following the guide on the official site. Unfortunately there's no section about logging on that guide.

A simplified version of my `__init__.py` is:

```
class MyFlaskExtension(object):

    def __init__(self, app=None)
        self.app
        if app is not None:
            self.init_app(app)

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.logger.debug('test')
```

This doesn't work, I'm not getting any errors but Flask is not printing my debug messages. If I replace my logger declartion with `self.logger = self.app.logger`, it works, using Flasks default logger. However, I want to handle the config and format for this separately from Flask.

How can I get Flask to print my extension's logs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your custom logger(with specific format and log level) you should register handlers. Here example which can help you `app.py`:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)


class MyFlaskExtension(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('my_flask_ext_logger')
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # your custom handlers, formatters and filters here...
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(logging.BASIC_FORMAT))
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)

        self.logger.info('My Was initialized')

    def init_app(self, flask_app):
        if not hasattr(flask_app, 'extensions'):
            app.extensions = {}

        app.extensions['MyFlaskExtension'] = self

        app.config.setdefault('DEFAULT_PARAM_OF_YOUR_EXTENSION', None)
        # other params
        app.config.setdefault('ONE_MORE DEFAULT_PARAM...', 5)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    # check your logger
    my_extension_logger = current_app.extensions['MyFlaskExtension'].logger
    my_extension_logger.info('Route "/". This is message from My extension logger')

    return 'logger'

# init and register your extension
my_extension = MyFlaskExtension()
my_extension.init_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Run our application. You will see the next output in console:

```
INFO:my_flask_ext_logger:My Was initialized
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Now let's open `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`. You will see message from your logger:

```
INFO:my_flask_ext_logger:Route "/". This is message from My extension logger
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2017 16:28:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Hope this helps.